How to customize my program's installer made with Tauri
How can i change the texts, background color, imagens and more in my program's installer?


You can customize using Wix Templates, here's an official documentation for it.
You can create extensions via wxs files and then extend the tauri configuration like this:
{
  "tauri": {
    "bundle": {
      "windows": {
        "wix": {
          "fragmentPaths": ["./path/to/registry.wxs"],
          "componentRefs": ["MyFragmentRegistryEntries"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Note, Tauri only support Wix Toolset v3 only for now.

Thanks for your time and sorry for not replying to your message, but I don't understand how to create the code with wix and how to link this file to my Tauri project. Can you give me a simple example?
